# In Jena, is there a way query subject via object?

Tags: java, jena

I have a turtle file like this:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05h40wd>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_id>   "21537998"  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05h40xf>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_id>   "21557390"  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05h4251>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_id>   "21550418"  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05h4__1>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_id>   "21495513"  .
```

I now only have the object(the id) but I want to get the subject. Is there a way? This is my code.

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new FileInputStream("RDFTest.ttl"),null,"TTL");
        Resource topic = model.getResource("http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/" + "m.05h4251");
          Property labelProperty = model.getProperty("http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_id");
          System.out.println(topic.getProperty(labelProperty));
  }
```

Ands the result is :

```
[http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05h4251, http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_id, "21550418"]
```

If I do the reverse I will get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Model#listResourcesWithProperty(Property p, RDFNode o)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listResourcesWithProperty%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29).  If you don't care what the property is, just pass **null** as the property to act as a wildcard.  This gives you a ResIterator over the subjects, because there could be more than one (just like there could be more than one object for a property for a given subject;  the method you're using getProperty, just returns an arbitrary one).

Comment: Thanks. In fact I have preprocessed the data so the relation is one to one. So it seems your way works.